# Is there an Android annotation to require that a method be called during Application.onCreate?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection

In my library, I have a singleton class will provide an interface. I want to require the an implementation of the interface to be set during Application.onCreate (via a static initialize() method).

Is there any way to ***require*** that this library method be called during Application.onCreate()?

```
public class LibraryDataProvider {

    private static IProvider theProvider = null;

    @MysteryAnnotation?
    public static void initialize(IProvider provider) {
        theProvider = provider;
    }

    public static IProvider get() { return theProvider; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to require the an implementation of the interface to be set during Application.onCreate (via a static initialize() method).

That's generally not a good practice. For example, a `ContentProvider` is created before `onCreate()` of `Application` is called. It also rarely solves a problem; lazy-initialization can often work as well, and that makes it easier for developers to avoid unnecessary work when starting up a process.

> Is there any way to require that this library method be called during Application.onCreate()?

To lightly paraphrase Neo from *The Matrix*: "You need guns. Lots of guns."

Otherwise, no, at least in terms of standard Android. For example, there is nothing in the `support-annotations` library that enforces what you want.

Comment: I wasn't aware of ContentResolver and ContentProvider. It seems like it may actually provide some of the characteristics I want. (It still fails to enforce the requirement that the ContentProvider be implemented, but at least it fails to do so in an idiomatic Android way so people won't yell at me about my code.